# Angular 10 - Extended component how to reuse base component's template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In Angular 10, I extended a component and wanted to reuse the base component's template and add relevant html in the extended component.

Edit: Reason I am attempting this is because I need the base component's functionality and add extra functionality in another area of the app. Based on this [article](https://medium.com/@gerard.sans/angular-2-new-features-in-angular-2-3-f2e73f16a09e).

How is this possible given these simple components?:

Base Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'base-component',
    template: `
        <p>base-component template</p>
    `
})
export class BaseComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

Extended Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponentComponent } from '../base-component/base-component.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'extended-component',
    template: `
        <!-- Add base component template here and not just by copy pasting... -->
        <p>add extended-component's relevant html</p>
    `
})
export class ExtendedComponentComponent extends BaseComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be on a wrong path. Components are normally composed instead of extending them. Could you please explain why such extension is necessary in the first place?

Comment: Iam open to being proven wrong, but I dont think that's the way you want to actually do this. I can imagine an element in your parent component with a directive that automatically inserts your base component during the `ngOnInit` cycle, possibly also with parameters, though.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I updated question with reason.

Comment: ng-content would fit great to your problem, you can place it inside your ExtendedComponent and when you want to use it do <extended-component><base-component></base-component></extended-component>, have you considered using this approach?

Comment: can't you just do `template: '<base-component></base-component>'`?

Answer (score 1):

Below simplified example of my BaseComponent:

```
//BASE
export class BaseComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  public isLoading  = false;
  public isEditing = false;

  constructor(
    protected dataService: EntityService<T>
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    //other common methods
}

//EXTENDED
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: '../base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../base.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent extends BaseComponent<User> {  
    constructor(
        protected dataService: UserService
    ) {
        super(dataService);
    }
}
```

Base html and css templates not defined into BaseComponent, just use them into extended. And I created base EntityService and BaseModule which I use only for import/export all needed modules. BaseComponent not defined into BaseModule.
Whole realization contain a lot rows, so I do not want to write here, but if you have questions - I'm ready to answer.